# Elegant architectures for react/redux frontends with django backends for editing large data model structures?

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, redux, django-rest-framework

### Context

We have a large Django application with a complex frontend that mixes several technologies. We are thinking about a big redesign and want to avoid some organic growth complexity from before, i.e. a lot of manual change tracking and individual endpoints in the REST API.

The data model spans a dozen Django applications and 156 tables in PostgreSQL. Some resources are very large and contain lists of mappings to other, smaller resources. As an example, an `AirplaneRepair`, a data structure describing a to-be-planned operation contains hardware and personnel requirements, both with constraints regarding *when* they are needed.

The frontend has a few common features that challenge the current architecture:

- auto-save on changes (similar to Google Drive)
- undo / redo (should work nicely with redux)
- versioning of operation-describing components (e.g. a version of the AirplaneRepair operation with all of its crew and hardware constrains)

  - stored as JSON blobs in the DB for now
  - created on explicit "create version" call by user

Otherwise it's mostly data manipulation with backend enforced constrains / consistency checks.

### The proposed new architecture

We defined all our models in Django. Those should stay. ORM maps them onto the DB.

#### API

The REST API should consist of **two** root parts

- `/api/v2/resources/` is supposed to give generic CRUD access to all models. Updates should be supplied using the JSON-Patch principles (i.e. just diffs instead of whole JSON blobs)

  - `?fields=field1,field3,field5` should allow filtering of the returned data to return only requested subfields
  - `?expand=field.children` should trigger `prefetch_related` or some other way to auto expand relations in the models and place them in the returned JSON
- `/api/v2/services/` holds any specific RPC calls that trigger complex action in the backend which don't map onto the resources

#### Frontend

The frontend is based on a combination of static "frames" and react components inside of those frames. We use `react-redux` to keep track of our data. Reading through [this discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/55n4r2/redux_and_rfc_6902_jsonpatch/), it seems others have tried marrying json-patch documents and redux/react. Generally, the action/reducers pattern of redux should allow for easy implementation of a few concepts mentioned above.

- UI displays data, based on the URL (i.e. resource and current view)
- edits to the data are wrapped in actions and reducers
- use [redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) to dispatch any data manipulation actions to the 
  backend
- update the redux store on ajax responses
- update the redux store through a websocket "notify" channel that allows the server to update its clients about changed 
  resources

### Open questions

- What are ways to generically expose all defined models in django via CRUD rest APIs (preferably with DRF)

  - How do we hook into the lifecycle here to handle the mentioned request parameters
- How should we map redux actions to PATCH / POST / PUT requests? Partial updates are especially interesting, as we 
  shouldn't send the whole JSON blob forth and back simply to update a single field
- Is JSON-Patch a widely used standard?

Comment: I am aware of the openness of the question. However, there is no architecture.stackexchange.com subpage so I went here. An alternative would be softwareengineering.stackexchange.com . Architecture inherently "depends", but I believe a mainly data manipulation frontend driven by the tech stack described is a very common case and a generic CRUD REST api that ties into the redux lifecycle is also a common pattern worth discussing.